# How to iterate through two lists without the use of nested "for" loops

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop

How do I iterate through two lists without the use of nested "for" loops?

the index between the two lists doesn't necessarily have to be the same

more specifically I am coding a function that takes a list of strings and a list of banned words. If any of the banned words are in each one of the strings, that whole string gets deleted.

I tried doing:

```
for word in bannedWords:
    for string in messages:
        if word in string:
            messages.remove( string )
```

This, however, doesn't work because the string variable is used in the "for" loop, so removing the string from messages will mess up the "for" loop. What is a better way to implement? Thanks.

Comment: It seems to me you need the nested 'for' loop to do what you want. Your issue is actually: "How do I delete an item from a list while iterating over it?". You can find some answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably do it in a line!

```
messages = [string for string in messages 
              if not any(word in bannedWords for word in string)]
```

Comment: `x` here will be a single letter.

Comment: It would be a word. Let me fix the poor variable naming choice.

Comment: However you name it, iterating over a string gives individual characters.

Comment: According to OP's code, it seems "messages" are a list of sentences, "string" is a list of words. Iterating over list of strings would give a "word" in each iteration.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses guys. Thrustmaster's algorithm seems to work perfectly and was exactly what I was looking for. Been struggling with this for a while. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Downvoter: Can you please explain? Please consider putting a comment while you downvote..

Answer (score 1):

I would probably write something like:

```
def filter_messages(messages, bannedWords):
    for string in messages:
        if all(word not in string for word in bannedWords):
            yield string
```

Now you have a *generator function* that will only give you good messages.  If you really want to update `messages` in place, you can do:

```
messages[:] = filter_messages(messages, bannedWords)
```

though the in-place requirement is rare:

```
messages = list(filter_messages(messages, bannedWords))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a set of banned words and a list of strings that might contain these bad words:

```
bannedWords = set("bad", "offensive")

messages = ["message containing a bad word", "i'm clean", "i'm offensive"]

cleaned = [x for x in messages if not any(y for y in bannedWords if y in x)]
```

Result:

```
>>> cleaned
["i'm clean"]
>>>
```